# How to watch net request in safari?

Tags: safari, webkit, httpwebrequest

I had seen developer tools in Safari. But does it shows net request? like we see in [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/network)..

How to see net request in Safari.

Currently I am using [safari webkit](http://webkit.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the developer toolbar there is a tab called Resources!